# Translate/convert ".nat" files to ".tif"

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have been downloading some soil-moisture data from "EUMETSAT: EO:EUM:DAT:METOP:SOMO12". The data is in **".nat"** form. I want to **translate/convert** the aforementioned to a **".tif"** form (or GeoTiff). I do not seek an online converter, as I intend to translate programmatically a very large number of files.

I had a similar issue concerning data in **".grb"** form and I wrote a **python scrpit** using **gdal_translate** command from **gdal** software. However, from my experience, **gdal** cannot translate **".nat"** files to **".tif"** (read-only compatibility exists).

My question is: How can I **translate/convert ".nat"** files to **".tif"** ?
Here is the similar python script I used for **".grb"** files with **gdal** tools:

```
def grbToTiff(input, output):
    cmd2 = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.1\\bin\\gdal_translate.exe"
    call(cmd2 + " " + input + " " + output)

in_path = ".\\data\\"
out_path = ".\\final\\"
files = listdir(in_path)

for f in files:
    grbToTiff(in_path+f, out_path + f[28:-20] + ".tif")
```

Comment: [Translating EUMETSAT’s .nat files to GTiff](https://www.dariusgoergen.com/contents/blog/2020-06-14-nat2tif/index.html) (in Python )